# Capture ftp hostname and uri using tshark (wireshark)

Tags: ftp, wireshark

I want to watch the ftp traffic and find which ftp urls are being accessed with tshark. For http traffic I can use

```
tshark -i eth0 -f 'port 80' -l -t ad -n -R 'http.request' -T fields -e http.host -e http.request.uri
```

Wireshark's Display Filters contains the fields http.request.uri and http.host
See: http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/h/http.html
But these options are not available for ftp traffic.
http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/f/ftp.html

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that FTP is not a stateless transactional protocol like HTTP - with HTTP the client does a single request which details all the parameters required to deliver the file, and the server responds with a single message that contains all the metadata and the file contents.

In comparison, FTP is a chat-style protocol: to get something done you open a connection to the server and starts chatting with the server - login, change to some directory, list files, get me this file, etc.

You can listen into this conversation using wireshark like this:

```
tshark  -i lo -f 'port 21' -l -t ad -n -R ftp.request.command -T fields -e ftp.request.command -e ftp.request.arg
```

The output received when a user tries to retrieve a file from the FTP server (in this example using the client software curl) might look like this:

```
USER    username
PASS    password
PWD
CWD     Documents
EPSV
TYPE    I
SIZE    somefile.ext
RETR    somefile.ext
QUIT
```

A bit of processing over that might give you a URL like log of file retrievals. For example, I came up with this thing using perl:

```
tshark  -i lo -f 'port 21' -l -t ad -n -R ftp.request.command \
  -T fields -e ftp.request.command -e ftp.request.arg | \
  perl -nle '
    m|CWD\s*(\S+)| and do { 
      $dir=$1; 
      if ($dir =~ m,^/,) { $cwd=$dir } else { $cwd .= "/$dir"; } 
    }; 
    m|RETR\s*(\S+)| and print "$cwd/$1";'
```

For the same FTP session above, this script will yield a single line of output:

```
/Documents/somefile.ext
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah I have already implemented a solution like this. Thanks for the answer anyway.